# I am getting this keyerror: 'groups' when trying to fetch nearby venues using Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

Hi I am getting `keyerror: 'groups'` when trying to fetch nearby venues using Foursquare API. Following is my code:

```
LIMIT = 100 # limit of number of venues returned by Foursquare API


radius = 500 # define radius

venues_list = []

for lat, long, post, borough, neighborhood, hospital in zip(hospital_df['Latitude'], hospital_df['Longitude'], hospital_df['Pincode'], hospital_df['District'], hospital_df['Location'], hospital_df['Hospital_Name']):
    print(neighborhood)
    print(borough)
    url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v= 
    {}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}".format(
        CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET,
        VERSION,
        lat,
        long,
        radius, 
        LIMIT)
    results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
    venues_list.append([(
            post, 
            borough,
            neighborhood,
            hospital,
            lat, 
            lng, 
            v['venue']['name'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
            v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
nearby_venues.columns = ['PostalCode', 'Borough', 'Neighborhood', 'Hospital', 'Neighborhood_Latitude', 'Neighborhood_Longitude', 'VenueName', 'VenueLatitude', 'VenueLongitude', 'VenueCategory']
```

I keep getting the following error:

> KeyError: 'groups'

Comment: What language is this?  Looks like Python.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue "KeyError: 'groups'" with very similar code. What I found was that while my URL variable that I built was incorrectly formed (I added a filter for categoryId, but I passed an incorrectly formatted variable for this value).

Once I corrected this formula, the "results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0['items']" was able to process without errors.

My guess is that when I submitted the incorrectly formed URL, the JSON return was an error message without the correct formatting that included 'groups'.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to exceeding the number of free calls to the Foursquare API in my case. I have very similar code, prewritten as part of an online course. I was running it fine for many days with no issues. Then, suddenly I got the 'groups' key error a few times. Then, I stopped working, and the next morning the code ran fine. Then, after a few calls I got the error again. So I checked the .json file, and it didn't contain the key 'groups' because it was basically a .json file telling me the quota was exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your CLIENT SECRET from Foursquare account. It worked for me.